# MySQL - Count rows with equal values but only if name occurs in other column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a table JT with the following columns:

```
Id  |  Name |  Date     
1   |  John |  2015-01-01
2   |  Alex |  2016-01-01
3   |  Pete |  2016-01-01
4   |  Alex |  2016-08-08    
5   |  John |  2016-08-08
```

I want to count the number of rows with the same date. I have done this by:

```
$query_21="SELECT Date, COUNT(*) AS total FROM JT GROUP BY Date";
$result_21=mysql_query($query_21);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_21)) {

    echo $row['Date'] . ":";
    echo $row['total'] . "<br>";     
}
```

That works fine returning:

```
2015-01-01: 1

2016-01-01: 2

2016-08-08: 2
```

However, I have a variable $Name, and I want to make the call so a row is only inserted in the resulting array if $Name is included in one of the rows during the count. So if $Name = "John" it should return:

```
2015-01-01: 1

2016-08-08: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a `where` clause using an `exists` condition, but since you're grouping anyway, I think using a `having` clause may be more elegant:

```
SELECT   Date, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM     jt
GROUP BY Date
HAVING   (COUNT(CASE name WHEN $name THEN name END) > 0)
```

**Note:**

`$name` should, of course, be a bound variable in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

it's also possible to use Mureinik's query with SUM and without use of COUNT in combination with CASE statement.
I think this query is more easy to read and understand because the query is more compact.

```
SELECT 
   total.Date
 , COUNT(*) AS total
FROM 
  total 
GROUP BY
  total.Date
HAVING 
  SUM(total.Name = "John")
```